# Redirection in liferay from beanclass

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, liferay, liferay-6

How to redirect from one page to another page from beanclass using Liferay?

Here is the code:

```
LiferayFacesContext portletFacesContext = LiferayFacesContext.getInstance();
portletFacesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("NewFile");
```

When this code executes, a message shows "Page not found". Both files are present in View folder of liferay project for JSF portlet.

Answer (score -1):

Your code fragment shows that you are mixing PortletFacesContext and LiferayFacesContext. Please make sure that you are using Liferay Faces jars (such as liferay-faces-portal.jar and liferay-faces-bridge-impl.jar) instead of the old jars from portletfaces.org

I would recommend that you only use LiferayFacesContext. Having said that, are you trying to redirect to a different JSF view within the same portlet on the same portal page? Or are you trying to redirect to a different portal page?